# The Vanishing of Greed, Hatred, and Delusion ~ Nyanatiloka

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras, translation

At the beginning of his talk, [The Vanishing of Greed, Hatred, and Delusion](https://tisarana.ca/the-vanishing-of-greed-hatred-and-delusion/),  **Ajahn Viradhammo** reads verses about Nibbana from a translation by Nyanatiloka of a fragment of the Pali Canon, from the Asaṅkhata Saṃyutta I suppose:

> This, Oh monks, is called the Unconditioned: the vanishing of greed, hatred, and delusion.
>   This Oh monks, is called the Boundless:  the vanishing of greed, hatred, and delusion.
>   This Oh monks, is called Freedom from [?]:  the vanishing of greed, hatred, and delusion.
>   This Oh monks, is called the True: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Further Shore: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Subtle: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the [?]: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Ageless: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Permanent: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Beyond of All Manifoldness: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Peace: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Deathless: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Sublime: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Auspicious: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the [?]: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Wondrous: ...
>   This Oh monks, is called the Sorrowless: ...
>   .. etc...

Is anyone aware of such a translation by Nyanatiloka being available on line ?

Thank you for having taken the time to read this, your kind and generous help is very much appreciated.

[image: Ajahn Viradhammo]

Comment: Maybe it can help: 
https://urbandharma.org/pdf/wordofbuddha.pdf ,
https://what-buddha-said.net/library/pdfs/Nyanatiloka_Buddhist_Dictionary.pdf ,
http://ftp.budaedu.org/ebooks/pdf/EN012.pdf

Comment: @beginner I don't think those contain the quoted text (but if they did it would be better to post it as a answer than as a comment, maybe with a page number too).

Answer (score 3):

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the taintless and the path leading to the taintless.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the truth and the path leading to the truth.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the far shore and the path leading to the far shore.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the subtle and the path leading to the subtle.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the very difficult to see and the path leading to the very difficult to see.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the unaging and the path leading to the unaging.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the stable and the path leading to the stable.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the undisintegrating and the path leading to the undisintegrating.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the unmanifest and the path leading to the unmanifest.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the unproliferated and the path leading to the unproliferated.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the peaceful and the path leading to the peaceful.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the deathless and the path leading to the deathless.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the sublime and the path leading to the sublime.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the auspicious and the path leading to the auspicious.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the secure and the path leading to the secure.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the destruction of craving and the path leading to the destruction of craving.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the wonderful and the path leading to the wonderful.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the amazing and the path leading to the amazing.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the unailing and the path leading to the unailing.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the unailing state and the path leading to the unailing state.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the Nibbana and the path leading to the Nibbana.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the unafflicted and the path leading to the unafflicted.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the dispassion and the path leading to the dispassion.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the purity and the path leading to the purity.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the freedom and the path leading to the freedom.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the unadhesive and the path leading to the unadhesive.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the island and the path leading to the island.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the shelter and the path leading to the shelter.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the asylum and the path leading to the asylum.

Bhikkhus, I will teach you the refuge and the path leading to the refuge.

[Samyutta Nikaya 43.14 to SN 43.43](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn43.14) translated by Bhikkhu Bodhi

Answer (score 2):

Possible source : The Buddha's Path To Deliverance ~ Nyanatiloka

https://books.google.fr/books?id=TjDkBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=manifoldness+nyanatiloka&source=bl&ots=OOSRkkkMWG&sig=1amC6GoSby-xpjiaImzTsE9bCpY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC4aeS6aHWAhVGPxoKHeFzBd8Q6AEIDzAC#v=onepage&q=manifoldness%20nyanatiloka&f=false

[image]

https://store.pariyatti.org/Buddhas-Path-to-Deliverance-The--eBook-ePub-Mobi-PDF_p_4830.html